# CSS: Gradients repeating in Chrome when set to tbody/thead

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, gradient

The problem I am having is shown here. Basically when I put a gradient on a thead, Chrome repeats that gradient for ever cell... The actual desired result is what firefox produced - a solid gradient for the whole thead.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the css I have:

```
thead.header {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: #C6C6C6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #DEDEDE 0%, #BDBDBD 80%, #BBB 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#DEDEDE), color-stop(80%,#BDBDBD), color-stop(100%,#BBB));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#DEDEDE', endColorstr='#BBB',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Here is the html if it helps:

```
  <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="header">
      <tr>
        <th width="200px">Actor</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Character</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Gender</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="odd">
      <tr>
        <td width="200px">Test</td> 
        <td rowspan="3">Test</table>
        </td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>Male</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML snippet you're applying that CSS to?

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem

Comment: Please mark one of the posted answers as correct, or provide more information so we can understand how to help you.

Comment: Resolved in Chrome v80, but still a bug in Safari (iOS13)

Answer (score 8):

Set `background-attachment:fixed;` on thead and it will work fine

Comment: This is what worked best for me. No need to reposition any TH-elements.

Comment: Awesome fix! Thank you! So simple and works like a charm!

Comment: This makes the gradient relative to the viewport, which makes it either look like it's not a gradient at all, or makes the gradient look different depending on the screen size. To make it look normal, you need a color stop at a fixed amount (like 50px). `linear-gradient(black, white 50px)`

Answer (score 4):

This is an unfortunate problem, but there is a simple work-around that will work for most layouts:

Set the gradient on the table itself, and give the `<td>`s a solid color.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vudj9/

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's because the `background` style can't be applied to the `thead` element.

Comment: I don't understand why not?

Answer (score 2):

Applying the gradient to the `th` element instead of the `thead` and using the `rowspan` attribute selector seems to work. This wouldn't work so well if the height of the two header rows were flexible as you need to know the middle range color `#7E7E7E` in the example. Checkout the exmaple http://jsfiddle.net/wSWF9/2/

```
   table {
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       border-collapse: collapse;
   }

   table thead th[rowspan="2"] {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #333);
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #333);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
   }

   table thead tr th {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #7E7E7E);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
   }

   table thead tr + tr th {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7E7E7E, #333);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you give the thead a value of `display: table-caption;` it works.

Needs some additional CSS for positioning of `th` content.

```css
thead.header {
  display: table-caption;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: #C6C6C6;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #DEDEDE 0%, #BDBDBD 80%, #BBB 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #DEDEDE), color-stop(80%, #BDBDBD), color-stop(100%, #BBB));
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#DEDEDE', endColorstr='#BBB', GradientType=0);
}

thead.header th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <th width="200px">Actor<br><br></th>
      <th rowspan="3">Character</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="odd">
    <tr>
      <td width="200px">Test</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great! I think this is the best solution. But what you mean by needs some additional CSS for the positioning of the th content?

Comment: At least in my chrome, the table is not a real table anymore with 100% width. You have to set the width of the ths manually.

Comment: Not a solution for me. It breaks the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a *way to circumvent* the problem is to not use separate cells, and to use `<br />` instead.

I realize that this is not a very good fix.

Your code: http://jsbin.com/ozuhi5

Your code with fix: http://jsbin.com/ozuhi5/2

New `<thead>`:

```
<thead class="header">
  <tr>
    <th width="200">
      Actor<br />
        Gender<br />
        Age
    </th>
    <th>Character</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: File a bug report and see what happens: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug on google chrome read more about it on [this Google page about issues on Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122988).

I do  have the same problem when trying to styling the tbody element, This is the solution I use to fix my code without breaking other browsers support:

```
table>tbody {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, black, white); /* keep the right code     for other browsers */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg, black, white);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, black, white);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, white);

    background-color: transparent; /* needed for chrome*/
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0)); /*del the linear-gradient on google chrome */
}
table {  /*fix tbody issues on google chrome engine*/
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 39px, black 0px,white ); /* 359px is the calculated height of the thead elemx */
    border-spacing: 0; /*delete border spacing */
}
```

See the demo on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j4Pv/)

Comment: It is fixed in Chrome, but the problem remains in Safari.